# Pandas select rows with a specific value in at least one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's take this sample dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],'Col1':[True,False,False],'Col2':[False,False,False], 'Col3':[True,False,True]})

   ID   Col1   Col2   Col3
0   1   True  False   True
1   2  False  False  False
2   3  False  False   True
```

I would like to select rows of df having at least one True. I can of course do the following :

```
df[df["Col1"] | df["Col2"] | df["Col3"]]
```

But my real dataframe has a lot of columns and consider I don't know their names. How please could I do ?

Expected output :

```
   ID   Col1   Col2  Col3
0   1   True  False  True
2   3  False  False  True
```

Comment: could you use a loop through them? There's also the `.any()`

Comment: How please do you use ```.any()``` ? I tried ```df[df[df.columns].any(True)]```but it is not the solution

Comment: like this: [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `any` function for the exact purpose:

```
df = df.set_index('ID', drop=True)
print(df[df.any(axis='columns')]

# output:
     Col1   Col2  Col3
ID                    
1    True  False  True
3   False  False  True
```

or without resetting the index:

```
print(df[df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].any(axis='columns')])

# output:
   ID   Col1   Col2  Col3
0   1   True  False  True
2   3  False  False  True
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to work because my dataframe has True/False values. But what if it was "A" and "B" values and that the objective is to have rows with at least a "A" value ?

Comment: Then you just covert the dataframe to bool values according to you requirements. I.e. in the case you mentioned, you first compare the dataframe with `A`, and call `any` on the resulting dataframe `(df == 'A').any(axis='columns')`

Answer (score 3):

you can use `.select_dtypes` and boolean filtering with `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.select_dtypes('bool').sum(axis=1).ge(1)]


   ID   Col1   Col2  Col3
0   1   True  False  True
2   3  False  False  True
```